# Selenium for Internet explorer on Jenkins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, ie11

Recently, my tests started failing.
I'm testing on IE11(company policy) on a jenkins windows slave.

My tests all hang on the "This is the initial start page" if I'm not connected to the server.
If I am connected, the tests run as they're supposed to.

I'm using java bindings 3.141.59 on IE WebDriver 3.15.

Comment: Have you set-up all prerequesties listed here - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is interacting with system's GUI that is responsible for drawing the windows and dispatching user interactions to certain UI elements. When you run your tests having remote desktop window open (or when you logged on the session on your local machine) Selenium can obtain GUI objects since it can see them just like you do.

Once you close or collapse remote desktop window or locks your local machine, GUI is getting terminated so nobody (including Selenium test) can interact with it. You can try to apply solutions which suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618774/jenkins-selenium-gui-tests-are-not-visible-on-windows). They implies some reconfiguration of the system that is hosting your Jenkins slave.